# jQuery validation of form in R/Shiny application

Tags: jquery, r, shiny, jquery-validate

Is it possible to use the [jQuery validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) to validate a form in an R/Shiny application?

I would like to take advantage of this great package in my applications

I wasn't able to get a minimal example, below, to work and I am having trouble identifying the issue.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- 

dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(),
dashboardSidebar(),
dashboardBody(
fluidPage(
includeScript('jquery.validate.min.js'),
    tags$form(id='myform',
     textInput('field1','label'),
     textInput('field2','label2'),
     submitButton('submit')
    ),


tags$script('
$(document).ready(function () {
$(\'#myform\').validate({ // initialize the plugin
           rules: {
             field1: {
               required: true,
               email: true
             },
             field2: {
               required: true,
               minlength: 5
             }
           }
           });

  });               

           ')
 )
 )
 )

 server <- function(input, output) {

 # Once form is validated, do something 

 }

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with "shiny" or "R".  However, jQuery Validate depends only on client-side JavaScript... not any other framework or language; and it certainly does not care about the server-side software.  That being said, in order for us to help, show the ***RENDERED*** HTML markup and JavaScript, not your Shiny server-side code.

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for an example of how to do this within the R/Shiny framework (shiny.rstudio.com). There are many great examples/tutorials on how to do this in HTML/Javascript.

Comment: Looking at the rendered html is how you would troubleshoot this.   It will show you where it’s broken so you can work backwards towards making Shiny correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, but a huge pain to do in Shiny. According to the jQuery Validation plugin docs:

> Mandated: A 'name' attribute is required for all input elements needing validation, and the plugin will not work without this. A 'name' attribute must also be unique to the form, as this is how the plugin keeps track of all input elements.

https://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/

Shiny [`textInput`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/textInput.html)s don't come with a 'name' attribute, nor do they provide an easy way to add one. You kind of have to hack around it - either construct your own textInput, or modify the existing one.

Second pain: Shiny catches and specially handles form submissions to make `submitButton` work. That means we can't rely on jQuery.Validate's built-in behavior of preventing invalid forms from being submitted. Instead, we have to work around it, using something like the [`showErrors`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#showerrors) callback to simply raise a flag if the form is invalid. It'll be tough to prevent an invalid form from being sent to the server, but at least you can check whether the inputs are valid before doing anything with them.

This example shows two ways of adding rules: pure markup, and a custom rules object like in your example. I recommend markup only for ease of use. See https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/ for examples.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# Use a CDN for the example, but can also be sourced locally
jQueryValidateLib <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
  "jquery.validate", "1.17.0",
  src = c(href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0"),
  script = "jquery.validate.min.js"
)

# Form validity status is accessible at input$formId_valid
validatedForm <- function(formId, ..., rules = NULL, options = list()) {
  options$rules <- rules
  tagList(
    jQueryValidateLib,
    tags$form(id = formId, ...),
    tags$script(HTML(sprintf("
      $(function () {
        var formId = '%s';
        var options = %s;

        options.showErrors = function(e) {
          var isValid = this.numberOfInvalids() === 0;
          Shiny.onInputChange(formId + '_valid', isValid);
          this.defaultShowErrors();
        };

        $('#' + formId).validate(options);
      });
      ", formId, toJSON(options))
    ))
  )
}

# Like textInput but allows adding attributes to the input element through ...
validatedTextInput <- function(inputId, label, value = "", width = NULL,
                               placeholder = NULL, ...) {
  inputContainer <- textInput(inputId, label, value = value,
                              width = width, placeholder = placeholder)
  inputElement <- inputContainer$children[[2]]

  attribs <- c(inputElement$attribs, list(name = inputId, ...))
  attribs[duplicated(names(attribs), fromLast = TRUE)] <- NULL
  inputElement$attribs <- attribs

  inputContainer$children[[2]] <- inputElement
  inputContainer
}

toJSON <- function(x, auto_unbox = TRUE, ...) {
  jsonlite::toJSON(x, auto_unbox = auto_unbox)
}

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    validatedForm(
      "myform",
      validatedTextInput("field1", "field1", required = TRUE, type = "email"),
      validatedTextInput("field2", "field2"),
      submitButton("Submit"),
      rules = list(field2 = list(required = TRUE, minlength = 5))
    ),

    verbatimTextOutput("fields")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$fields <- renderPrint({
    cat(
      paste("field1:", input$field1),
      paste("field2:", input$field2),
      paste("myform_valid:", input$myform_valid),
      sep = "\n"
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

Here's what the generated HTML looks like:

```
<form id="myform">
  <div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
    <label for="field1">field1</label>
    <input id="field1" class="form-control" value="" name="field1" required="TRUE" type="email"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group shiny-input-container">
    <label for="field2">field2</label>
    <input id="field2" type="text" class="form-control" value="" name="field2"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
<script>
$(function () {
  var formId = 'myform';
  var options = {"rules":{"field2":{"required":true,"minlength":5}}};

  options.showErrors = function(e) {
    var isValid = this.numberOfInvalids() === 0;
    Shiny.onInputChange(formId + '_valid', isValid);
    this.defaultShowErrors();
  };

  $('#' + formId).validate(options);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this Greg, it's very helpful to see it implemented in Shiny. There seems to be a problem with the initialisation of the plugin though - clicking Submit on app start-up does not seem to trigger validation (the "This field is required" message is not displayed) even though both required fields are empty, would it please be possible to confirm this on your end? I have tried it on Chrome and Firefox with the same result. It's weird because `console.log($('myform').valid())` correctly returns `false`.

Comment: Also, if you correctly fill in one field on app start-up while leaving the other blank and then hit Submit, the required field message is not displayed for the blank input. `input$myform_valid` is also `TRUE` even though one of the required fields is empty but `console.log($('myform').valid())` still returns `false`.

Comment: I suspect it might have something to do with how Shiny loads the app because it works in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1xs5oy0v/2/).

Comment: It seems to work if a regular button is used instead of a submit type button - http://jsfiddle.net/1xs5oy0v/3/.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive if it will work, but you may have better luck with using the shinyJS package from Dean Attali, specifically with extendshinyjs().

See https://deanattali.com/shinyjs/ and https://deanattali.com/shinyjs/extend

Look at this template from Dean's website and see the obvious swaps you can make with your `$(document).ready()` validation part:

```
jscode <- "
shinyjs.init = function() {
  $(document).keypress(function(e) { alert('Key pressed: ' + e.which); });
}"

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    extendShinyjs(text = jscode),
    "Press any key"
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {}
)
```

Please post back here if it works.